# What is the "address" being returned from GetProcAddress()?

Tags: winapi, dll, getprocaddress

I'm a little bit confused with `GetProcAddress()`.
Quoting the Win32 docs:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the address of the exported function or variable.

I know that for functions, `GetProcAddress()` returns a function pointer that calls the desired function. However, it isn't clear what `GetProcAddress()` returns in something like this:

**DLL code**

```c
typedef struct {
  uint64_t foo;
  double bar;
  char* baz;
} MyStruct;

__declspec(dllexport) MyStruct* my_struct_ptr;

__declspec(dllexport) long long special_global;
```

**Application code**

```
void* my_struct_ptr = GetProcAddress(my_dll_handle, "my_struct_ptr");
void* special_global = GetProcAddress(my_dll_handle, "special_global");
```

What would `my_struct_ptr` and `special_global` in the application point to?

EDIT: Does `my_struct_ptr` point to the DLL's `my_struct_ptr` or the struct that the DLL's `my_struct_ptr` points to?

Comment: in case variable exported - address of this variable. type of variable not play any role

Comment: `my_struct_ptr` point to the DLL's `&my_struct_ptr`